# Use verbatim with \only in beamer

Tags: beamer, verbatim

I want to have a frame to showing text and then data ( in verbatim ).
And I cant compile it.

I made this minimum working example :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\only<1>{
\begin{verbatim}
test slide 1
\end{verbatim}
}

\only<2>{
test slide 2
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I get this error :

```
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.17 \end{frame}
```

So is using `\only` a bad solution ?

Comment: Verbatim content as an argument to another command is not possible (at least not this way)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\defverbatim{\foo}{\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\defverbatim{\testslide}{\begin{verbatim}test slide 1  $E=mc^2$\end{verbatim}}

\only<1>{%
\testslide
}

\only<2>{
test slide 2
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another solution is to put the verbatim content in a box (\newsavebox\box etc). Then, use the content within your frame with \only<2>{ \usebox{\box} }. This worked well for me.