# \end tag ignored in frame

Tags: beamer, listings, verbatim

I have the following slide in a document of class *beamer*.

```
\begin{frame}{Modular Design}

    \begin{lstlisting}

        <code>

    \end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}
```

This however returns [these errors.](http://pastebin.com/4HgGUaDu)
Thinking it might be the `listings` package which is faulty, I retried with

```
\begin{frame}{Modular Design}

    \begin{verbatim}

        <code>

    \end{verbatim}

\end{frame}
```

...which returns

```
! Paragraph ended before \@xverbatim was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.170 \end{frame}
```

Therefore my questions are:
1. What do I do wrong?
2. How can it be fixed?

P.S:
I compile it using the Quickbuild of Kile, which apparently uses just
`pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode name.tex` to compile.

Comment: Try the `fragile` option to the frame environment. The basic error is to try `verbatim` content inside without special caution: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305719/use-verbatim-with-only-in-beamer/305722#305722, for example

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well, that worked. Thanks!